# How can I pass the body of a TikZ node to a font-changing macro?

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, nodes, implicit-braces

After looking around at some other answers on this site, I'm trying to typeset a tree using the tikz-qtree package.  It works great, but by design it does not let you use macros in the tree nodes, unless you use the two specific macros `\node` and `\edge` to define TikZ nodes and edges directly.

What I'd like to have is something along the lines of

```
\tikzset{every tree node/.style={
   execute at begin node=\code\bgroup,
   execute at end node=\egroup}}
```

where at the moment, `\code` locally sets up some symbols and then sets the text in TT font:

```
\newcommand{\code}[1]{{\def\_{\wild}%
                       \def\"{\quot}% dummy " for hightlighting...
                       \def\~{\symbol{126}}%
                       \def\^{\symbol{94}}%
                       \texttt{#1}}}
```

This compiles, but doesn't typeset the node text in TT font.  Bizarrely, if I just change \impl to \texttt directly, it *does* typeset in TT font.  I know that TikZ plays around with null fonts and such, to ensure things get typeset only when they're supposed to, so I'm not terribly surprised that this font-changing of a node is tricky.

I saw in another question that it's suggested to use `\begingroup`/`\endgroup` instead of `\bgroup`/`\egroup`.  I tried that, but LaTeX complains about "Missing } inserted; Extra } or forgotten \endgroup"

A minimum (non-)working example is below:

```
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary[trees]
\newcommand{\code}[1]{{\def\_{\wild}%
                       \def\"{\quot}% dummy " for hightlighting...
                       \def\~{\symbol{126}}%
                       \def\^{\symbol{94}}%
                       \texttt{#1}}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[grow=down]
  \tikzset{every tree node/.style={
      execute at begin node=\strut\code\bgroup,
      execute at end node=\egroup}};
  \Tree [.html head body ]
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I'm not sure whether my use of `\bgroup`/`\egroup` is wrong, or whether my definition of `\code` is faulty...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't give you a direct answer to your problem, but I can give you an alternative, more direct solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}

\begin{document} 
\newcommand{\code}{\def\_{\wild}%
                   \def\"{\quot}% dummy " for hightlighting...
                   \def\~{\symbol{126}}%
                   \def\^{\symbol{94}}%
                   \ttfamily}

\begin{tikzpicture}[grow=down]
    \tikzset{every tree node/.style={font=\code}}
\Tree [.html head body ]
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

---

Also, for whatever reason, when I remove one of the group in your definition of `\code`, your example works as expected. Maybe that extra group confuses TikZ?

Comment: Not sure what the expected etiquette is for old questions; since this alternative solution worked for my particular problem, I'm accepting it as the answer, but it doesn't quite give the direct answer to the problem...  Either way, @Caramdir, thanks for this alternate approach :)