# Filter tikz node text through macro

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, tikz-styles

I would like to make a node style that "filters" the node's label (text) through a command, i.e. replace the node text with a macro, with the original node text passed as an argument to that macro. Specifically, in this case, I want to add a node `\node {C}` and have it typeset/draw `\node {$\mathbb{C}$}`.

I read the following answer: [How can I pass the body of a TikZ node to a font-changing macro?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17521/how-can-i-pass-the-body-of-a-tikz-node-to-a-font-changing-macro) and thought to do it like there, inserting `$\mathbb\bgroup` into the `execute at begin node` and `\egroup$` into the `execute at end node`. This works (see MWE below), but I thought it would be better to use `\ensuremath`; also I might want to use `\bm{\mathbb{C}}` or `\pmb{\mathbb{C}}` for an 'extra-bold blackboard bold' symbol.

As soon as I add `\ensuremath\bgroup` or the extra `\bm\bgroup`, however, I get errors. Also if I define a separate macro `\mymacro` and use that in the tikzstyle definition, I get errors (see MWE below). Also when defining this macro somewhat differently (inspired by [Use node text as argument for a macro](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18518/use-node-text-as-argument-for-a-macro)) do I get errors.

Is there any way to achieve this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsfonts} %for the mathbb command
\usepackage{amsmath}

\tikzset{
  bb/.style={
    execute at begin node=$\mathbb\bgroup,
    execute at end node=\egroup$
  }
}

\tikzset{
  bb2/.style={
    execute at begin node=\ensuremath\bgroup\mathbb\bgroup,
    execute at end node=\egroup\egroup
  }
}

\def\mymacro#1{\ensuremath{\mathbb{#1}}}
\tikzset{
  my macro/.style={
    execute at begin node=\mymacro\bgroup,
    execute at end node=\egroup
  }
}

\def\mysecondmacro{\ensuremath\bgroup\mathbb\bgroup}
\def\endmysecondmacro{\egroup\egroup}
\tikzset{
  my secondmacro/.style={
    execute at begin node={\mysecondmacro},
    execute at end node={\endmysecondmacro}
  }
}

\begin{document}
  In text: \ensuremath{\mathbb{C}} %simply as text

  bb style: \tikz \node[bb] {C}; %produces the blackboard-bold C

  % Gives errors "Missing } inserted.", "\mathbb allowed only in math mode"
  % and "Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup."
  bb2 style: \tikz \node[bb2] {C}; %produces the blackboard-bold C

  % Gives errors "Missing } inserted" and "Extra }, or forotten \endgroup"
  my macro style: \tikz \node[my macro] {C};

  % Gives same error as bb2 style
  my second macro style: \tikz\node[my secondmacro] {C};

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\mathbb\bgroup C\egroup` works by pure chance; `\ensuremath\bgroup...\egroup` will definitely not work.

Comment: Yes, egreg, I noticed this. Could you enlighten me why this is so?

Comment: The braces around an argument should be explicit `{` and `}`. You can't say `\mbox\bgroup X\egroup`, for instance, because you're passing `\bgroup` as the argument to `\mbox`. The fact that such a construct *seems* to work doesn't mean it really does; the same is for `\mathbb` or other math family changing commands. For other macros you'll get unscrutable errors.

Answer (score 5):

The latest version of PGF has a `node contents=<node text>` key which can be used in place of the `{<node text>}` in a node. It could be used like this:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5]{standalone}
\tikzset{node text/.style={node contents=\transformtext{#1}}}
\def\transformtext#1{\ttfamily(#1)}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \l [count=\y] in {a,...,e}
  \node [draw] at (\y,\y) [node text=\l:\y];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]